# Nginx redirect all subfolders but the folder itself

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a weird clash of names for a Wordpress installation, and I need to write a couple of Nginx rules to fix it.

I used to have my software projects listed in the Wordpress page */projects*, with links to sub-pages */projects/aprojectname*, */projects/anothername*, etc.

Recently, I bought a theme with a custom post type for portfolio items.
It is called *project* (note the missing *s*).

At */project*, I access the default Wordpress listing of all the *project* posts. Then, I can access the posts using */project/aprojectname*, */project/anothername*, etc.

So far, so good. The issue is that I would like to use the new /project structure preserving any previous link to my /projects/something. Also, I would like to keep the /projects page only (no redirect).

This is what I would like to accomplish.

1. The URL */project* **only** should redirect to */projects*, so that I can show a Wordpress page instead of the "ugly" Wordpress listing of posts.
2. Consequently, The URL */projects* **only** should not be processed. It should display the corresponding Wordpress page.
3. However, **all** URLs in the form */projects/something* should redirect to */project/something*

This is my nginx rule so far.

```
location ~ ^/projects/(.*) {
   return 301 http://$server_name/project/$1;
}
```

This works good for 3.:  /projects/aprojectname -> /project/aprojectname.

It does not work for 2.,  because it rewrites /projects to */project*

I have no clue how to implement 1., as any attempt will affect the previously written rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~ ^/projects/(.+) {
    rewrite ^ http://$server_name/project/$1 permanent;
}
```

The .+ instead of .* fixes the issue, since .+ matches 1 or more characters, while .* matches 0 or more characters. Therefore the /projects/ folder is not touched by the rule.

For 1, the following should work:

```
location = /project {
    rewrite ^ http://$server_name/projects permanent;
}
```

`location =` is the exact matching directive for nginx, so it only matches if the URI is exactly `/project`.

I also replaced the return 301 directive with rewrite -directive, as that is preferred way of doing rewrites.

- Tero